# Convert Zoned Decimal from an Ebcdic file to a Java String

Tags: java

Is there anyone tried to to the captioned conversion before? Actually, I would like to do something below:

```
public static Object parseZonedDec(byte[] byte_array) throws Exception {
  String val = getHexString(byte_array);
  int len = val.length();
  return val.substring(1, len-1); // not sure if this is correct?
}

public static String getHexString(byte[] b) {
  if (b == null) {
    return null;
  }

  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

  for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++)
  {
    sb.append(Integer.toString( (b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
  }
  return sb.toString().toUpperCase;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run this? Is there an error? Does it compile? Is the output incorrect?  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for details on using this site effectively.  Also, did you look up the specification for zoned decimal?

Comment: Please clarify more, what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code

```
    public long parseZonedDec(byte[] data) {
    long val = 0L;
    boolean negative = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int raw = data[i] & UNSIGNED_BYTE;
        int digitA = raw >> 4;
        int digitB = raw & BITS_RIGHT;

        if (digitA < 10) {
            val *= 10L;
            val += (long) digitA;

        } else if (digitA == 11 || digitA == 13) { 
            negative = true;
        }

        if (digitB < 10) {
            val *= 10L;
            val += (long) digitB;

        } else if (digitB == 11 || digitB == 13) {
            negative = true;
        }
    }
    if (negative)
        val = -val;
    return val;
}
```

Comment: If length of zoned decimal field = 4, does it mean String.length() will be equal to 4 as well, unlike packed decimal? BTW, can you explain the above logic a little bit? Thanks a lot!